# IF statement in python with request.form.get()

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to do "INSERT INTO table (...)" in SQlite database depending on which option the user selects on my website. Here is part of my html (on top) and python (bottom):

```
<form action="/calendar" method="post" autofocus name="name" placeholder="name" type="text">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="expenses">
                <option disabled selected value>Expenses</option>
                    <option value="home">home expense</option>
                    <option value="food">food expense</option>
                    <option value="child">child expense</option>
                    <option value="debt">debt expense</option>
                    <option value="healthcare">healthcare expense</option>
                    <option value="transportation">transportation expense</option>
                    <option value="personalcare">personalcare expense</option>
                    <option value="petcare">petcare expense</option>
                    <option value="entertainment">entertainment expense</option>
                    <option value="others">others expense</option>

            </select>


if request.method == "POST":
        # return apology page if anything isn't provided correctly
        note = request.form.get("note")
        amount = float(request.form.get("amount"))
        if amount < 0:
            return apology("provide positive amount")

        if request.form.get("home"):

            db.execute("INSERT INTO home (id, amount, note, date) VALUES(:id, :amount, :note, :date)", id=session["user_id"], amount=usd(amount), note=note, date=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

        elif request.form.get("food"):

            db.execute("INSERT INTO food (id, amount, note, date) VALUES(:id, :amount, :note, :date)", id=session["user_id"], amount=usd(amount), note=note, date=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

If I don't use if statement it inserts the data properly, but with if statement it doesn't. Could someone give me an explanation for this or give me alternative ways to achieve the same result with python and SQLite datebase?

Comment: There's no form element with `name="home"`, what are you expecting `request.form.get("home")` to be?

Answer (score 0):

There's no form input with `name="home"` or `name="food"`. Those are just the values of options in the `<select>`, whose name is `expenses`. What you want is:

```
expenses = request.form.get("expenses")
if expenses == "home":
    db.execute("INSERT INTO home (id, amount, note, date) VALUES(:id, :amount, :note, :date)", id=session["user_id"], amount=usd(amount), note=note, date=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
elif expenses = "food":
    db.execute("INSERT INTO food (id, amount, note, date) VALUES(:id, :amount, :note, :date)", id=session["user_id"], amount=usd(amount), note=note, date=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```